# Equally resizing columns with interacting elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I am attempting to code the following image:

[image: Example]

My goal is that when the browser is resized, the notch in the middle stays proportionate and both columns scale equally.

Here's my code:

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 22px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  max-width: 575px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.container svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Right column, the image has is a png with the notches. */
img {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <svg width="575" height="604" viewBox="0 0 575 604" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1143_882)">
            <g clip-path="url(#clip1_1143_882)">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9 0C4.02944 0 0 4.02945 0 9.00001V595C0 599.971 4.02944 604 9 604H466C470.971 604 475 599.971 475 595V495C475 490.029 479.029 486 484 486H566C570.971 486 575 481.971 575 477V9C575 4.02944 570.971 0 566 0H9Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip0_1143_882">
              <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip1_1143_882">
              <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
        </svg>
  </div>
  <img src="example.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

I've tried CSS masking too but haven't had any luck. I guess an alternate plan is to use the entire section as a background image, but I'm curious if my initial approach can be salvaged.

Here's the svg code for the entire section:

```html
<svg width="1396" height="656" viewBox="0 0 1396 656" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1143_887)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip1_1143_887)">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9 0C4.02944 0 0 4.02945 0 9.00001V595C0 599.971 4.02944 604 9 604H466C470.971 604 475 599.971 475 595V495C475 490.029 479.029 486 484 486H566C570.971 486 575 481.971 575 477V9C575 4.02944 570.971 0 566 0H9Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1362 611C1362 606.029 1366.03 602 1371 602H1387C1391.97 602 1396 597.971 1396 593V11C1396 6.02943 1391.97 2 1387 2H605C600.029 2 596 6.02944 596 11V495C596 499.971 591.971 504 587 504H506C501.029 504 497 508.029 497 513V647C497 651.971 501.029 656 506 656H1353C1357.97 656 1362 651.971 1362 647V611Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_1143_887">
      <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip1_1143_887">
      <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you just add style="width: 100%" to your parent SVG element, it scales to the window and everything stays proportional.

```html
<svg style="width: 100%" width="1396" height="656" viewBox="0 0 1396 656" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1143_887)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip1_1143_887)">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9 0C4.02944 0 0 4.02945 0 9.00001V595C0 599.971 4.02944 604 9 604H466C470.971 604 475 599.971 475 595V495C475 490.029 479.029 486 484 486H566C570.971 486 575 481.971 575 477V9C575 4.02944 570.971 0 566 0H9Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1362 611C1362 606.029 1366.03 602 1371 602H1387C1391.97 602 1396 597.971 1396 593V11C1396 6.02943 1391.97 2 1387 2H605C600.029 2 596 6.02944 596 11V495C596 499.971 591.971 504 587 504H506C501.029 504 497 508.029 497 513V647C497 651.971 501.029 656 506 656H1353C1357.97 656 1362 651.971 1362 647V611Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_1143_887">
      <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip1_1143_887">
      <rect width="575" height="604" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Agreed, I would set `display: block; height: auto; width: 100%;` on the SVG